# Bootstrap modal didn't work on host server

Tags: modal-dialog

i am facing a problem with bootstrap modal. where in localserver, the modal can work, but it's not working in host server.

```
<button data-target="#classModal<?php echo $prog['idPrograms']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" id="MainNavHelp" class="btn btn-primary px-4 mx-auto mb-4">Details</button>

<!=================================== MODAL HERE ===================================-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="classModal<?php echo $prog['idPrograms']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document" style="overflow-y: none; max-height:85%;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
                    <?php echo $prog['class']; ?> Class
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo $prog['progDesc']; ?><br />
                <div class="row border-bottom">
                    <div class="col-5 py-1 text-right border-right"><strong>Age of Kids</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 py-1"><?php echo $prog['age']; ?> Years</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row border-bottom">
                    <div class="col-5 py-1 text-right border-right"><strong>Total Seats</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 py-1"><?php echo $prog['limitSeats']; ?> Seats</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row border-bottom">
                    <div class="col-5 py-1 text-right border-right"><strong>Class Time</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 py-1"><?php echo date('H:i', strtotime($prog["startTime"])); ?> - <?php echo date('H:i', strtotime($prog["endTime"])); ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row border-bottom">
                    <div class="col-5 py-1 text-right"><strong>Registration Fee</strong></div>
                </div>
<?php
    $idClass = $prog['idClass'];
    $qFee = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM fee WHERE idClass = '$idClass'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while($fee = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qFee)){
?>
                <div class="row border-bottom">
                    <div class="col-5 py-1 text-right border-right"><small><?php echo $fee['descFee'].' <i>('.$fee['period'].')</i>'; ?></small></div>
                    <div class="col-6 py-1"><small>IDR. <?php echo number_format($fee['amountFee'],0,',','.'); ?></small></div>
                </div>
<?php } ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!=================================== MODAL ===================================-->
```

i've tried many ways, but still cannot figure out where the problem is.